# fromPromise cause "pipe is not a function" Redux-observable

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm new to rxjs and redux observable.

fromPromise cause the error.

FCM.getFCMToken() is API like fetch.
It returns a string.

My code is below.

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

const successLoginWithSessionTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.SUCCESS_LOGIN_WITH_SESSION_TOKEN),
  fromPromise(FCM.getFCMToken().pipe(
    map((deviceToken: string) => actoins.updateDeviceToken(deviceToken)),
  )),
);
```

Is it right way to use fromPromise?

Comment: No, that's not how `fromPromise` should be used. [`fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) takes a `Promise` and returns an `Observable`. You appear to be using it for something ... different.

Comment: Is it async/await problem?

Is
fromPromise(somePomise).pipe(
...
no problem?

Comment: You should check the parentheses in your snippet. As it is, the code makes little sense. `FCM.getFCMToken().pipe(...)` won't evaluate to a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you close a parentesis a litlle late, what you want to do is execute functions in this order:

> fromPromise() => obserbable => .pipe()

What you need is something like this

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

const successLoginWithSessionTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.SUCCESS_LOGIN_WITH_SESSION_TOKEN),
  fromPromise(FCM.getFCMToken()).pipe(
    map((deviceToken: string) => actions.updateDeviceToken(deviceToken))
  ).subscribe(() => {});
```